# What happens when I make reference to subclass as a abstract base class type

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference, abstract-class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void f() {cout << "hi" << endl;}

    void g() { cout << "bye" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A &a = b;
    a.f(); // prints "hi"
    a.g(); // compile error no member g()
    return 0;
}
```

why does `a.g()` give compile error while `a.f()` calls B's f()?
At `A &a = b;` does the compiler somehow set a boundary of where a's aliasing memory ends?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to call `g()` from an instance of `A`. `A` does not have an implementation of `g()`, so it cannot be called through an `A` object. The fact that `a` is a reference to a `B` does not give `a` access to any functions that `A` does not know about.

`B`, on the other hand *is-a* `A`, and defines an implementation of the virtual function `f()`, so the reference `a` invokes the correct function.